# Using topic in WL.Server.readSingleJMSMessage leads to class cast exception

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

JMS comes with two flavors: p2p messaging (queues) or publish/subscribe (topics). To my surprise it is not symmetric in JMS adapter. Queues works fine two ways, reading and writing. For topics only writing (publishing) works as expected, reading from topic (subscribing, non-durable way) fails when message is published to topic WL adapter listens to. Logged error is:

```
com.ibm.ws.sib.api.jms.impl.JmsTopicImpl cannot be cast to javax.jms.Queue
FWLSE0101E: Caused by: null
```

Documentation shows no limitations on using topics, thus for me the concept of "destination" in JMS is simply mishandled.

Answer (score 2):

Reading from a topic is not supported in JMS adapters in Worklight. The documentation will need to be updated to either include this or make it more clear.

Comment: It is a pity. Pub/sub is more complex I agree but leaving just P2P support with couple bugs in 2 tested functions makes me thinking twice before using it :(

Comment: Off topic: why Worklight does not provide a server-side framework similar to Cordova on client-side i.e. ability to create own Java implementation and expose it as adapter in JS? With such a generic adapter and moderated community it would result with more adapters and less work for core Worklight team. Who cares about eclipse wizard or XML configs if it barely gives functionality...

Comment: jedreg, that is a good point and would open up Worklight to be more community oriented. Perhaps it is something that could be considered in the future.